# android Auto-Rotate configuration on change listener

Tags: android, listener, autorotate

I want to listen to 'Auto-Rotate' configuration change,  not the device/system orientation, but to the toggle changes (on/off)
I believe i will have to sign up to configChange in the AndroidManifest and create a listener wherever i want but i'm not sure what is the correct config.
I.E.

```
android:configChanges='??'
```

But maybe another way exists and not through the `android:configChanges` ...

Comment: This is the question ... what should i sign up for ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4435473/1620542 take a look at that, should be what you want

Comment: Try this link https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android:configchanges

Comment: configChanges will only notify you when the rotation changes (among other things), you want to know when the Auto Rotate setting changes no?

Comment: @Eluvatar , yes, you are right, it might be in another way ... i just thought it will  be this way,  Can you please expand how the first link should help ? i wasn't able to understand where the auto-rotate comes in..

Comment: @sankarV , sorry it doesn't help, already tried it.

Comment: this should be more what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/7017516/1620542 you will need to tweak it to work for you but it should be fine, just remember that setting is in Accessibility.

Comment: check my answer.. although it is downvoted by some one :( but my answer is what you wanted... it responds when the auto rotation button is clicke

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you have to listen to Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION using a content observer.

To register the content observer

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Settings.System.getUriFor
(Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION),
true,rotationObserver );
```

And declare it here. The onChange method will be called when the rotation is changed.

```
private ContentObserver rotationObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
           Do your task
        }
};
```

Comment: he does not want to know when the device has rotated, he want's to know when the auto-rotate setting in accessibility has changed.

Comment: @Eluvatar I have posted exactly what he wanted.. From next time please check before downvoting

Comment: @Eluvatar .. please dont downvote someone if you are not sure about something