# how to make Notification appear after checking data in mysql in android

Tags: android, mysql

So I have this program who needs to check every 30 seconds from a database to check whether a status in my database is 0 or 1 and if i updated the status in my database from 0 to 1 there should be any notification occurred i do not use gcm because i don't know why i can't use it so i use a timer to check for every 30 seconds the problem is after it checks and show me a notification it won't stop notify me every 30 seconds even though there is no other data in my database with status 1 can someone help please?thank you before. :)

Comment: Nice wall of text, what does it say?

Comment: sorry I'm still new to this i just try to ask and find an answer to my question perhaps if you need more details about the code then i will try to add it later,thank you anyway. :)

Comment: Try to use ContentObserver in Your Code to Listen to Data Changes
chek this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422410/how-to-implement-a-contentobserver-for-call-logs

Comment: Sorry still can't understand about how to really implement the content observer cause i'm still newbie to this android thing,sorry but still thank you. :)