# Android : Dialing number removing from call log for 1st time and not for 2nd time

Tags: android

I want to remove the dialing number from my call log. For that I have written BroadCastReceiver and inside the receiver method I have written the code like this.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
          phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER); 
          Log.i("sadas",phoneNumber);
     }
     else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
         TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {  
         context.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,   CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ?", new String[] { phoneNumber });
     }
     else{

     }
  }
```

The above code is working with some issue. If i call the number for first time then it is removing and for second time it is not removing. Likewise for sometime it is removing.

I can't figure out the problem. Whether I did mistake at anywhere?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: when if condition is executing second time?

Comment: Better is to register observer for Call log change into service. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422410/how-to-implement-a-contentobserver-for-call-logs